# Axiom of choice for n-elements sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Assume that $C_n$ represents axiom of choice for sets that contain $n$ elements. Prove that if $n$ is a factor of $m$, we can conclude $C_n$ from $C_m$.

Here, I don't know what axiom of choice for n-elements set is. I know the first and second form of axiom of choice but I don't know how it is related to this problem and how to solve it.

Comment: I'd have written that as "... axiom of choice for families of sets that contain $n$ elements" for clarity. The alternative interpretation, "... axiom of choice for families that contain $n$ sets" is not as intriguing since choosing among a finite number of sets does not require any special axiom, but follows from induction on $n$.

Answer (score 7):

The Axiom of Choice is

> Given a set $X$ consisting of non-empty sets, there is a function $f: X\to\bigcup X$ such that $f(x)\in x$ for all $x\in X$.

Where would it make sense to change the axiom to consider only sets of size $n$? I'm no mind reader, so I cannot say for absolute certain what the problem author meant. But I would be **very** surprised if $C_n$ was anything other than this:

> Given a set $X_n$ consisting of sets of size $n$, there is a function $f:X_n\to\bigcup X_n$ such that $f(x)\in x$ for all $x\in X_n$.

As for how to solve the problem (assuming this is what is meant), assume $n$ is a factor of $m$, and assume $C_m$. Take a set $X_n$ consisting of sets of size $n$. Now we want to apply $C_m$ on some set $X_m$ comprising sets of size $m$. How can we make sets of size $m$ if what we have are sets of size $n$? Products seem like the obvious choice. And so we apply $C_m$ to $$X_m=\left\{x\times\{1,2,\ldots,\frac mn\}\mid x\in X_n\right\}$$If we take the resulting function $X_m\mapsto \bigcup X_m$, it is not very difficult to construct the choice function $X_n\to \bigcup X_n$ that we want from that, by considering the composition
$$
X_n\to X_m\to\bigcup X_m\to\bigcup X_n
$$
where the first map takes $x$ to $x\times \{1,2,\ldots,\frac mn\}$, and the last map is projection onto the first component.

Comment: In particular, restricting the cardinality of $X$ itself just yields special cases of finite choice, which is provable in ZF.

Comment: @mudri That would be the only other option that even makes semantic sense, and it would not make for a good exercise. Besides, I don't think there is any natural way to show $C_m\implies C_n$ from $n\mid m$ in that case.